# Statistical test for single sample vs empirical distribution?

Tags: nonparametric, small-sample, resampling

I have a sort of strange problem, where my sample is difficult to obtain, but the population distribution is easy to obtain.  Specifically, I have obtained a single observation.  I would like to know if it comes from a particular population.  A closed form for the population distribution is not known, but I can resample it ad infinitum and obtain an empirical distribution to any desirable degree of accuracy.  Judging by the pretty-picture method, the distribution is not normal enough to assume normality, but is normal enough for me to wonder if there is something better to use here than [Chebyshev's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality).

Are there any Nonparametric methods that can be used to test a single observation against an empirical distribution?

Comment: If your null hypothesis is that the sample observation did come from that population then then there is a $5\%$ probability that the sample will be in top tail or bottom tail of the known samples from the population.  So take your  resamples (one less than a multiple of $40$ might work) and look at the ranked position of the observation you are interested in among these

Comment: Do you have any specific (perhaps intractable) alternative distribution(s) in mind?

Comment: @jbowman, not really... I could probably fit e.g. a Gamma to it with some success, since it "looks like" a skewed normal and is guaranteed to be > 0.  OTOH, I have no a priori reason to expect the population to be gamma, so a nonparametric form would really be preferable.

Comment: @jbowman aaaaahhhhhh, I think I take your meaning now.  You mean that if I had some other hypothesis for the population distribution besides the one I can empirically determine, I could employ the [Likelihood Ratio Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test)?

Comment: Something along those lines, yes.   But if you don't, you don't.

Answer (score 0):

There is no statistical test because you have a sample, not a sampling distribution. You can compute distance metrics (eg, Z-score in case of normal distributions) but this would not be an inferential test

Comment: "but this would not be an inferential test" Are you making a semantical claim or an existential one?

Comment: An accurate claim. Inferential tests make assumptions that do not accommodate single point estimates.

Comment: You mistake my meaning.  Do you intend to say that nothing can be logically inferred about the likelihood that a point estimate belongs to a particular population with a known distribution, or do you intend merely to say that such an inference is not properly "statistical inference"?

Comment: If it is the former, then I would posit a simpler analogy, wherein I get a single point estimate of "7", and ask the question "what is the likelihood that this is the result of a coin flip?"  Clearly some kind of inference can be made here, although perhaps "statistical inference" is not the correct label.

Comment: If I have a null hypothesis that my data is distributed Gaussian $(0,1)$, and I observe a single value of $6$, it seems to me I can certainly apply a test and reject the null; the non-rejection region for $H_0$ might be, e.g., $(-1.96, +1.96)$ or some such, but it's still a test.

Comment: You can call it a test but it is not a inferential test. Meaning, with NHST you are making an inference about an unobserved population based on a sample statistic. A single observation is not a statistic. That said you can calc the p(obs) given h(distribution), yea, but it doesn’t allow you to generalize